# Regex NLTK chunking - Can't get my regex rule to identify certain pos tags

Tags: regex, nlp, nltk, pos-tagger, chunking

Hi I am attempting to identify very specific sentence structures but the rule i am writing in regex seems to skip occasional parts of my test samples. Here is an example:

```
chunkRule= r"""Action: {<PRP|PRP$|NNP|NN>+<VB|VBD|VBG|VBN|VBZ|RB|JJ|NNP|NN>+<VBG|RP|RB|NNP|NN|PRP$>*}"""
```

Input text: My wife goes out

POS Tag: [('My', 'PRP$'), ('wife', 'NN'), ('goes', 'VBZ'), ('out', 'RP')

Return Value: (Action wife/NN goes/VBZ out/RP)

As you can see it's skipping "My"/PRP$ POS tag. Does anyone have any ideas how to adjust this to allow it to detect this?

Thanks for your help in advanced!

Comment: Code to reproduce is missing.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to define a rule for 3-word sequences. If so, your rule doesn't match a structure like PRP$ -> NN -> VBZ. I don't know what you're expecting as an output. If it is: "Action my/PRP$ wife/NN goes/VBZ", add `VBZ` to your third word:

```
chunkRule= r"""Action: {<PRP|PRP$|NNP|NN>+<VB|VBD|VBG|VBN|VBZ|RB|JJ|NNP|NN>+<VBG|RP|RB|NNP|NN|PRP$|VBZ>*}"""
```